# How would I modify this script to convert all files recursively?

Tags: macos, script, conversion

```
#!/bin/bash
#convert
for image in *.png; do
        convert  "$image"  "${image%.png}.jpg"
        echo “image $image converted to ${image%.png}.jpg ”
done
exit 0
```

I'm a Python programmer and from some functionality in `pathlib` I would have thought that `**/*.png` should do the trick, but it seems to be going only one child deep in the directory tree.

PS: I'm on OSX

Comment: Hint: research `shopt -s globstar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `for` loop to go over all PNG files, this might be best achieved with

```
while read image; do
        test -f  "$image"  || continue
        convert  "$image"  "${image%.png}.jpg"
        echo “image $image converted to ${image%.png}.jpg ”
done < <(find . -name '*.png')
```

Comment: Better: [`IFS= read -r image`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This doesn't change a thing: We are not `read`ing an arbitrary text, but the output of `find`, which has a well-known structure (e.g. no backslashes)

Comment: Bare `find` prints pathnames terminated by newline characters. There will be `./` (starting location) in front, `.png` at the end. The rest is arbitrary. I think in general macOS/OSX and its filesystems allow backslashes in pathnames. Am I wrong? (I think they also allow newline characters, these would mislead `read image` and `IFS= read -r image` alike.)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Neither backslashes nor newlines are possible with files, that can be touched by finder. Backslashes in filenames are possible within the shell (Caveat: My knowledge about OSX is quite some years old)

Comment: There is no guarantee the files were created or touched (or whatever) by Finder. `IFS= read -r` is a good practice in such case, even if sole `read` works for the OP. So is double-quoting all variables in Bash (variables after `echo` in your code are not quoted). Code on SuperUser (StackExchange in general) should promote good practices and should be somewhat defensive because it can be picked up by any newbie with similar problem. With this in mind I gave you an improvement on a silver platter. I won't bother you here anymore.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski If you think my answer is bad, just downvote it and write your own. I copied as much code as possible from the OQ (including the quoting) to make sure the differences come out. I tend to not use unnecessary and overly complicated additions, that hide the gist of the answer.